# Notepad v.s. other platforms

Tags: html, web

Lately i have been using Notepad ++ and i was wondering if any of y'all would recommend a different platform that would allow me and another person to code on the same project at the same time?

Comment: Look at cloud 9 ide. Also, this is better for the [Web Apps stackexchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like using Sublime text.
It's very lightweight and extemely versatile :).
You can install alot of free very creative plugins to help you coding too including some SVN plugins.

To share your code another way i guess you could use something like github or tortoise SVN too.

To work on thesame file online i recommend collabedit.com (Online editor for multiple users)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Er, well, you could try Vim or Aptana Studio or Net Beans?